# select from two tables (count , order by , group by) codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a sql command , it is work but I can't using it in Codeigniter ,

when I use it in phpmyadmin it is works

> SELECT online_visitors.page_id , hotels.hotel_name ,
>   count(online_visitors.page_id) as count_visit FROM `online_visitors` ,
>   `hotels` WHERE online_visitors.page_type = 'hotel' AND
>   online_visitors.is_bot = 0 AND hotels.ID = online_visitors.page_id
>   group by online_visitors.page_id order by online_visitors.page_id asc

but when I want to useing it in codeigniter code I can't

```
$this->db->select("page_id , hotel_name");
$this->db->from("hotels");
$this->db->join("online_visitors");
$this->db->where("is_bot", 0);
$this->db->where("page_type", 'hotel');
$this->db->group_by("page_id");
$this->db->order_by("page_id");
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: And what debugging have you tried that you can present to us :)

Comment: check ypur query, it doesn't have join.But you are tryong to use it in  CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by 2 methods as mentioned

```
$query=$this->db->query(
'SELECT online_visitors.page_id , hotels.hotel_name , count(online_visitors.page_id) as count_visit FROM online_visitors , hotels WHERE online_visitors.page_type = 'hotel' AND online_visitors.is_bot = 0 AND hotels.ID = online_visitors.page_id group by online_visitors.page_id order by online_visitors.page_id asc'
);
```

and you can access `$query` as object

or you can break it down using [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Crap I never read his question... yes, Active Record is crap at joins, do them manually like this!

Comment: you can enable profile 
$this->output->enable_profiler();
to see what is the generated query from the code to MYSQL

Answer (score 2):

You could try this by using CodeIgniter active records with join

```
    $this->db->select('ov.page_id , h.hotel_name, count(ov.page_id) as count_visit ');
    $this->db->from('online_visitors as ov');
    $this->db->join('hotels as h','h.ID = ov.page_id');
    $this->db->where('ov.page_type','hotel');
    $this->db->where('ov.is_bot',0);
    $this->db->group_by('ov.page_id');
    $this->db->order_by('ov.page_id',"asc");
    $this->db->get();
```

Comment: This is most correct way to do it... Only use alias instead of full table name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("online_visitors.page_id , 
hotels.hotel_name,count(online_visitors.page_id) as count_visit");

$this->db>where("online_visitors.page_type = 'hotel'");
$this->db>where("online_visitors.is_bot = 0");
$this->db>where("hotels.ID = online_visitors.page_id");
$this->db->group_by("online_visitors.page_id");
$this->db->order_by("online_visitors.page_id", "asc");
```